# Spring @Value resource injection of test AND main resources

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring service that reads XML files from classpath. The XML resources are injected by `@Value` like

```
@Value("classpath:xyz/*.xyz.xml")
private Resource[] xyzResources;
```

Now, in a unit test, this will find XML files placed under *src/test/resource* but not under *src/main/resources*. **Why? And how can I get files from both resources folders in test environment?**

My Spring version is 5.0+, spring boot 2.0+.

Comment: Try`@Value("classpath*:xyz/*.xyz.xml")`  instead.

Comment: Amazing @aristotll! It works. Do you have any reference to documentation? I do not really know where to look for.

Comment: Resource path wildcards are mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths. Although not in context of resource files but for ApplicationContexts.

Comment: The classpath*: prefix is also mentioned in the doc of PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As solved in the comments:

```
@Value("classpath*:xyz/*.xyz.xml")
private Resource[] xyzResources;
```

The `*` behind `classpath` did the trick. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html).